# trying to clone a branch using git, but it doesn't work

Tags: git

```
$ git clone gitosis@tony:stylingGit2.git
Cloning into stylingGit2...
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm trying to connect to a server, this happens and I wouldn't know what to do...

...does anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either gitosis is misconfigured on the server, or you actually don't have access to it.

You should check the configuration of the host "tony" (and possibly compare it to others).

Comment: update saying that another user can clone the repo to their local machine, but im getting this error. im using cygwin

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the error message you don't have permission to read that directory. Do you have access to the server? then you can try `chmod`ing och `chown`ing it so that your user can access it.

Comment: update saying that another user can clone the repo to their local machine, but im getting this error. im using cygwin